# Script to replace tokens with values mentioned in properties file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file values.properties which contain data, like:

```
$ABC=10
$XYZ=20
```

I want to create a shell script that will take each element one by one from above file.

Say $ABC, then go to file ABC.txt & replace the value of $ABC with 10.
Similarly, then go to file XYZ.txt and replace $XYZ with 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe this should be in the Unix and Linux section, the solution I've hacked together is as follows:

```
cat values.properties  | grep "=" | cut -d "$" -f2 | awk -F "=" '{print "s/$"$1"/"$2"/g "$1".txt"}' | xargs -n2 sed -i
```

The flow is like so:

1. Filter out all the value assignments via: grep "="
2. Remove the '$' via: cut -d "$" -f2
3. Use awk to split the variable name and value and construct sed replacement command
4. Use xargs to pull in the replacement parameter and target file via: xargs -n2
5. Finally pass sed to as the command to xargs: xargs -n2 sed

Comment: Upvoted, good hack. This will work for variables with naming convention `$ABCD`  in the destination file, but will not work for `${ABCD}`. Kindly update the command to cover both scenario.